# Нужно загрузить картинки из компютера на сайт с помошью React JS

Tags: reactjs

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    padding: 3% 9%;
}

.for-lanes,
.second-lanes,
.third-lanes {
    display: flex;
    /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
}

.for-lanes {
    margin-bottom: 7%;
}

.kane {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    padding: 5px 13.5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: all .300s ease;

}

.kane:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;

    transition: all .300s ease;

}

.first-lane {
    width: 60%;
    /*height: 63px;*/
}

.second-lane {
    width: 20%;
}

.third-lane {
    width: 20%;
}

.fa-globe-europe {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.fa-map-marker-alt {
    margin-right: 10px; 
}

.fa-ellipsis-h {
    color: #ABB6B8
}

.second-kane {
    margin: 2px;
}

.from-flex {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

.for-two {
    padding-right: 32px;
    padding-left: 32px;
}

.second-lanes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.name {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ABB6B8;
}

.first-block-for-text {
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.for-smir {
    width: 13.5%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.for-icn {
    padding-left: 35px; 
    padding-right: 45px;
}

.for-down {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    left: -65px;
    top: 33px;
}

.for-down-two {
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    left: -210px;
    top: 33px;
}

.for-img-down {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-up {
    width: 65%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.img-down {
    width: 25%;
}

.in-down-img {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.for-inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.for-li {   /*Icon*/
    font-size: 500%;
    color: gray;
}

.second-inside {
    margin: 5% 0;
}

.for-down-link {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 13.5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;

    transition: all .300s ease;
}

.for-down-link:hover, .exit:hover {
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .300s ease;
}

.down-right  {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    height: 195px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.for-seli {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: gray;
}

.fa-dollar-sign { /*Icon*/
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.in-bott {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.for-three {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-left: 60px;
}

.for-down-kane {
    opacity: .5;
    padding-right: 80px;
    padding-left: 80px;
}

.down-mar {
    padding: 5% 5%;
}

.for-size {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #00bc00;
}

.exit {
    transition: all .300s ease; 
}

.last-is-last {
    background: #00bc00;
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="second-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text">
                Комната в квартире
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                студия
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                3
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                5
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                6
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                7
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                более
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                Этаж
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane for-icn">
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane for-icn">
                <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="for-down">
                Всего
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="third-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                Площадь
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane for-two">
                <span class="name">123...</span>
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane for-two">
                <span class="name">123...</span>
            </div>
            <span class="for-down">
                Жилая
            </span>
            <span class="for-down-two">
                Общая
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="second-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                Санузел
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Раздельный
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Совмещенный
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                Балкон
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Балкон
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Лоджия
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Нет
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                Отопление
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Центральное
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Район
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Свое
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                Газ
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Есть
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Нет
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                Канализация
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Центральное
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Своя
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second-lanes from-flex">
            <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                Горячая вода
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Есть
            </div>
            <div class="kane second-kane">
                Нет
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="for-img-down">
            <div class="img-up">
                <div class="in-down-img">
                    <div class="for-inside">
                        <div class="first-inside">  
                            <i class="far fa-images for-li"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="second-inside">
                            <span class="for-down-link">Выбрать файлы на компьютере</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="third">
                            <span class="for-down-in-link-second">Перетащите сюда файлы или выберите на компьютере</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="second-lanes from-flex down-mar">
                    <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir">
                        Цена
                    </div>
                    <div class="kane second-kane for-down-kane">
                        123...
                    </div>
                    <div class="kane second-kane">
                        <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h in-bott"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="kane second-kane for-three">
                        Торг возможен
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr style="opacity: .5;">
                <div class="second-lanes from-flex down-mar">
                    <div class="first-block-for-text for-smir for-size exit">
                        Войти
                    </div>
                    <div class="kane second-kane last-is-last">
                        Зарегистрироватся
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="img-down">
                <div class="down-right">
                    <i class="far fa-images for-seli"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="down-right">
                    <i class="far fa-images for-seli"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="down-right">
                    <i class="far fa-images for-seli"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="down-right">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus for-seli"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</boyd>
```

Comment: Reactjs тут причём?

Comment: Это с помощью ReactJS делают?